# Cross compiling Chromium browser for embedded linux

Tags: mips, cross-compiling, embedded-linux, chromium

We want to run chromium browser in embedded linux running on MIPS platform. Is it achievable?
If yes, how do we proceed?
We are seeing that chromium build system (gyp) does not have cross compiling option.

Comment: You should be paying attention to this page in future: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=130022

Comment: Thanks... That means currently its not supported